# Using FakeItEasy, is it possible to create a dummy object of a type that takes generic type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, xunit.net, fakeiteasy

I have the following test:

```
[Fact]
public void StartProgram_CallsZoneProgramStart()
{
    var zone = A.Fake<Zone>();
    zone.StartProgram();
    A.CallTo(() => zone.ZoneProgram.Start(null, A.Dummy<ActionBlock<InterruptInfo>>())).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
}
```

It's creating a dummy of type `ActionBlock<InterruptInfo>` which is being passed into the MustHaveHappened call. zone.StartProgram definitely calles the zone.ZoneProgram.Start method, but this call is not seen by FakeItEasy. It returns the following error message:

```
Assertion failed for the following call:
  ZoneLighting.ZoneProgramNS.ZoneProgram.Start(<NULL>, ActionBlock\`1 Id=1)
Expected to find it exactly once but found it #0 times among the calls:
  1: ZoneLighting.ZoneProgramNS.ZoneProgram.Start(inputStartingValues: Faked ZoneLighting.ZoneProgramNS.InputStartingValues, interruptQueue: ActionBlock`1 Id=2)
  2: ZoneLighting.ZoneProgramNS.ZoneProgram.Start(inputStartingValues: <NULL>, interruptQueue: ActionBlock`1 Id=2)
```

As can be seen from the error message, the ID on the ActionBlocks being compared are different (1 and 2), which is why it's not able to see that the call is made. My question is, why is the ID of the dummied ActionBlock = 1? I thought being a dummy object, it shouldn't have any concrete details in it like ID etc. Is this because generic types cannot be dummied?

I saw something similar here: https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/402

But I wasn't able to figure out if that's talking about the same thing or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with `ActionBlock`s, so am not sure where they get their `Id` values from, but I think I can shed some light on what's going on in your test.

First, I think you're confused about what a `Dummy` is. If so, don't feel bad. They can be a little confusing. From the [Dummy documentation](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dummies/), a Dummy is

> Dummy is an object that FakeItEasy can provide when an object of a certain type is required, but the actual behavior of the object is not important.

They are mostly used by FakeItEasy itself when it needs to create an object to feed to class constructors (we'll see more about that later), or when it needs to return a non-fakeable object from a method or property. It's rare for end users to have to create them.

A Dummy is an actual object (it has to be—otherwise, how could we do anything with it?). It has to have whatever concrete details in it that its type has (in this case, `ActionBlock<InterruptInfo>`). There are no restrictions against Dummying generic types.

Looking at the docs for [how a Dummy is made](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dummies/#how-are-the-dummies-made), we can see that since `ActionBlock<InterruptInfo>` probably doesn't have a custom `IDummyDefinition` available (do you have one?), and it's not a Task, and it's not fakeable (because the class is sealed), then the Dummy is made by invoking one of the [ActionBlock constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194839(v=vs.110).aspx), with Dummies being made to satifsy each of the arguments.

I guess that ActionBlocks have IDs. How they're assigned, I have no idea, but if they're a good ID, then it looks like we have two different `ActionBlock<InterruptInfo>`s: one provided in `zone.StartProgram`, and the Dummy made in the test.

The ActionBlocks documentation suggests that it doesn't override `Equals`, so a reference comparison will be performed, and the two ActionBlocks (the Dummy and the one used in the production code) don't match. This is why FakeItEasy doesn't recognize the call.

If you were just trying to see if any call to `zone.ZoneProgram.Start` was made with the first argument `null` and the second argument some ActionBlock, I think you might've meant to use:

```
A.CallTo(() => zone.ZoneProgram.Start(null, A<ActionBlock<InterruptInfo>>.Ignored))
            .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

(`Ignored` can also be shortened to `_`. Read more about [ignoring argument values](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/#ignoring-arguments) if you're so inclined.)

That may get you past your immediate problem, although I have concerns about two things:

1. It looks like `zone.ZoneProgram.Start` is being called twice, not "Exactly.Once", but I'm sure you'll be able to deal with this, and
2. In general, faking the object under test is considered to be an anti-pattern. Typically one supplies fake dependencies to the production code under test. I'm not saying it won't work, but sometimes it can lead to confusion. Still, it may be a problem for another day, after the current question has been resolved.

I hope that helps a little.

Oh, and you asked about Issue 402. That issue is about giving users more power when defining customization classes that will control how dummies are created. Unless you've made a class extending `IDummyDefinition` or `DummyDefinition`, it's probably not relevant at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I was not aware that sealed classes cannot be dummied up like this. So my follow up question is: From a testing perspective, how would one know if to use a dummy or use the .Ignored technique? In both cases, the type is needed but the actual behavior of the object is not important (quoting the Dummy documentation from your reply).

Comment: As to your point about faking the object under test being an anti-pattern, why is that the case? What if we are just testing the "plumbing" of the object to make sure that parts that are supposed to be connected are connected in terms of method calls? How would one go about testing this without faking the object?

Comment: `Ignored` is used when the argument passed to the call doesn't matter. In general, for call-matching semantics, the [Argument Constraints](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Argument-Constraints) techniques are the ones to use. A Dummy, once constructed, is an object like any other, so supplying it in the `A.CallTo` means it will be compared with the actual argument using `Equals`. If you want the comparison to say "true", then you _do_ care about the answer, so a Dummy is a bad choice. Even if it happens to work, it won't be clear why.

Comment: Regarding the anti-pattern, it's well and good that `StartProgram` calls `ZoneProgram.Start`, but we don't know what `ZoneProgram` is here—it's something that `zone` made up, as far as I can tell. The fact that the internal parts are connected is important, but something that only the object should be concerned about—we usually care about externally-visible behaviour. Checking the internal plumbing mostly just makes code difficult to refactor.
Of course, this is just a guideline. You may have a valid case for testing this way, and without the whole picture, maybe I shouldn't've commented.

Comment: And to clarify, sealed classes can be Dummies. It's just that they aren't Fakes at all. They're just instances of the class that have been instantiated using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This helped me understand things a lot better. I'll have to spend a little more time understanding how Fakes and Dummies are created, maybe that will help me understand it more.