# How can I Fake Base Class method using FakeItEasy

Tags: mocking, fakeiteasy

Am trying to use FakeItEasy. I have a particular scenario for which either am unable to understand how to test or is not possible using FakeItEasy

Lets say I have a base class and derived class which look like this

```
public class BaseClass {
     protected bool BaseClassMethod() { return true; }
   }

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
     public void DoSomething(){
        if(BaseClassMethod()) Console.WriteLine("Bla");
        else Console.WriteLine("Worked");
  }
}
```

Now I want to be able to test the DerivedClass, but be able to fake BaseClassMethod(). I tried doing something like

```
var fakeBaseClass = A.Fake<BaseClass>();
A.CallTo(fakedBaseClass).Where(x => x.Method.Name   "BaseClassMethod")).WithReturnType<bool>(). Returns(false); 
var derivedClass = new DerivedClass(); // Am hoping that the DerivedClass will use the Faked Baseclass that I have created above.
derivedClass.DoSomething()
```

This doesnt do what I expect it to do. Am i missing something here or is this not possible with FakeItEasy?

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach.

The first problem is that you've no connection between the `fakeBaseClass` you created and `derivedClass`, so there's no way for them to influence one another. To accomplish what I think you are trying to do, you really want to make a fake `DerivedClass` and manipulate its behaviour (actually, in general, this type of testing is contentious, but let's focus on the mechanics and set aside whether it's a good idea for now).

By faking `DerivedClass`, FakeItEasy will actually be instantiating a new type of class that *derives from `DerivedClass`* and therefore will call and have access to all (protected or public) methods of `DerivedClass` and `BaseClass`. Then you can set up the behaviour you want from `BaseClassMethod` and exercise `DoSomething` and hopefully get the results you want.

The second thing that will cause problems when we try this is that `BaseClassMethod` is not virtual. FakeItEasy (and isolation frameworks of its ilk) cannot fake out any method that is not virtual. You can learn more about what's fakeable at [What can be faked](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/).

So, putting together those two changes, I get code like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual bool BaseClassMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        if (BaseClassMethod())
        {
            return ("Bla");
        }
        else
        {
            return ("Worked");
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
{
    var fakedDerivedClass = A.Fake<DerivedClass>();
    A.CallTo(fakedDerivedClass)
        .Where(x => x.Method.Name == "BaseClassMethod")
        .WithReturnType<bool>()
        .Returns(false);

    Assert.That(fakedDerivedClass.DoSomething(), Is.EqualTo("Worked"));
}
```

This test passes. Note that I've made changes to your original (aside from correcting typos):

1. `BaseClassMethod` is now virtual
2. I'm creating a fake `DerivedClass` for testing, and
3. `DoSomething` returns a string, rather than writing to the Console. That wasn't strictly necessary, but made my test easier to write.

Note that if `BaseClassMethod` is not virtual, then there's no chance it will return anything other than `true`, and I don't see much point in writing a test to see what will happen when `DoSomething` gets a `false` from it.

For more discussion on why faking the class under test (instead of that class's *collaborators*) may be a bad idea, see comments on [Use FakeItEasy's A.CallTo() on another method in same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929758/use-fakeiteasys-a-callto-on-another-method-in-same-object) and my answer to [Using FakeItEasy, is it possible to create a dummy object of a type that takes generic type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682370/1199).

But how you feel about the approach is something that you will have to come to terms with on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your response was to the point and well written